# Is operating system an abstraction?

Tags: assembly, dos

How does it matter if you assemble, link and load an assembly language code or C code in DOS environment or Windows environment? shouldn't result be the same? after all execution is done by microprocessor, not operating system. I am learning assembly language from an old book of MS-DOS era. Is it a setback? isn't assembly language and its code execution, O/S independent? or for that matter any code written in other languages?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> isn't assembly language and its code execution, O/S independent?  or for that matter any code written in other languages?

Yes and no.

Yes.  The machine's language is independent of OS.  Doesn't matter if you wrote it yourself or the C compiler wrote it for you.

No.  You have to use an OS to actually run the software.  If you want it to do something *useful*, you'll need to call OS API's.  That is entirely OS dependent.

Comment: @ S lott So what would be the exact role of OS in running the software? copying it into the memory, allocating memory segments, copying first instruction address to IP? but in doing all this, how does it matter if the software is an assembly program or C ? What I mean to ask is that for an OS an executable file is an executable file, no matter which language it has been written, which compiler it has been compiled with.

Comment: @Saurabh: "how does it matter if the software is an assembly program or C ?"  (1) it doesn't matter and (2) that's not what your question asks.  Please **update** your question if it's not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the operating system "standardizes" the communications between our programs and the processor, so that printf() will behave as expected on both linux and windows (and others), on many different versions of those OS and on different hardware configuration.
And, *theoretically*, is possible to run the same program on the same processor with differents OSs, since opcodes are obviously the same, but this doesn't happen due to a matter of money (guess what would happen if one day linux could run windows's applications..).
So, although the possibility to run or not a binary should depend only to the processors, it depends on OSs too.